# Binding on Fragment Without Model Name

Tags: sapui5

Is it possible to do binding on a fragment without model name?

I have a fragment in a XML view. In the controller of the view I am doing an element binding to a simpleform in the fragment like this:

```
this.cpForm.bindElement({ path: sPath, model: "Customers" });
```

Now in the fragment when I am doing binding to a control I have to specify the model name otherwise the value is not displayed:

```
<Text xmlns="sap.m" text="{Customers>firstName}"/>
```

Please advice.

Comment: This is just the way UI5 works. If a model has been named when setting it, you need to use that name everywhere. Otherwise it would be impossible to distinguish between different models (e.g. you can have an i18n model and an OData model side-by-side). You can have ONE unnamed model in your app (use the empty string in the manifest.json or omit the name when calling `setModel`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can explicitly assign a model to your fragment as an unnamed model, in that case you can omit model name in the binding.
For example, you can obtain named model instance with this (I assume you have this named model in the view):

```
var oCustomersModel = this.getView().getModel("Customers");
```

then assign it to the fragment:

```
this.cpForm.setModel(oCustomersModel);
```

element binding would look like this:

```
this.cpForm.bindElement({ path: sPath });
```

finally, the control binding should look like this:

```
<Text xmlns="sap.m" text="{firstName}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the sPath is correct, try this syntax by adding the "/" before the attribute name:

```
<Text xmlns="sap.m" text="{Customers>/firstName}"/>
```